# How to show the each variable name at multiple line chart when using mouseover and mouseout? (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to show each variable name which is text when mouse hover the line and I using the mouseover and mouseout methods to trigger it but it hasn't shown any text which is variable name on the line chart and also it doesn't pop up any error message on console.

```
 var margin = {top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 60},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
     height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

 svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(sumstat)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", function(d){
      return d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(+d.Price); })
        (d.values)
        })
    .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
          svg.append("text")
            .attr("class", "title-text")
            .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.key) })  //it will return the different colors based on different variable names   
            .text(d.key) //it will return the different variable names   
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .attr("x", (width-margin)/2)
            .attr("y", 5);
        })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          svg.select(".title-text").remove();
        })
```

I will expected the variable name such as the city name which is the text, will show on the line chart when I use mouse to hover this line and if the mouse moves to another line at the same line chart then it will show the present variable name which is the previous variable name will disappear. So, I think maybe it can use the "mouseover" and "mouseout" methods in this case, but now it cannot show anything when the mouse hover each line and also doesn't pop up any error message.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino
Thanks for the replying and I try to use d3 to show the variable name like country in the line chart (please see the [link](https://codepen.io/zakariachowdhury/pen/JEmjwq)).
However, it cannot work on my line chart which it doesn't show any country's name on the top of the line chart!

Comment: Is it possible if you reproduce the issue on jsfiddle or codepen?